ggimage::geom_image creates funny blank spaces (R, ggplot2)
I'm trying to include some images in a plot with ggimage::geom_image, but I get some funny blank spaces in the plat, over the images and the theme lines (specially visible in the hands at 30 and 60 degrees). Does anyone have any clues why this is happening?

It is not related to coor_polar, or the scale_x_continous. It also happens after removing those.
Reprex
data
data <- data.frame(
    orientation_plot = c(84.8687178823166,
                         36.1605224623345,85.490835909266,118.364920417778,
                         323.571100970265,83.5318718305789,353.573855249211,
                         3.25847818609327,89.5467418483458,116.063044563401,
                         32.3134804693982,23.1578823705204,54.6099763480015,
                         66.4289224175736,31.5925489142537,126.763391675893,
                         3.04277477227151,NA,356.573548378423,59.2806502482854,
                         285.336272749119,91.6934458506294,57.422423563432,
                         27.819330428727,267.739669714589,74.1346866232343,341.468317054678,
                         18.5945961484686,297.035266268067,305.203626196831,
                         358.700171240605,6.04703434510157,23.6489164703526,
                         9.00754619669169,95.1137517741881,122.616225694772,
                         36.673466748558,36.3341428400017,10.4223038847558,
                         27.8741467655636,53.6461459486745,0.400726237799972,
                         54.7994793592952,73.9346079020761,38.3156356043182,
                         4.55477796355262,NA,75.7983187856153,83.6073278645054,
                         275.758351990487,338.891899047885,44.7995097832754,
                         266.699377262034,25.8976544588804,61.3590761739761,
                         274.032349750865,354.218091700692,16.542791841086,
                         25.9322731303982,273.790452339686,63.6962230657227,
                         20.0262956572697,114.584762491751,215.570711459499,
                         271.207204657141,343.967557917349,0.895052859559655,
                         353.356162891258,285.975557857659,328.662482370157,
                         4.18437166046351,4.54817786673084,358.290239455178,
                         323.249732512981,1.57666315464303,2.81194112543017,
                         55.2859467351809,235.159281685017,265.001678407192,
                         319.304464177229,55.4162168144248,245.138605715241,
                         58.8588382429443,9.76248261565343,89.7497630789876,
                         353.789504924789,273.88414450502,60.3621193352155,
                         357.865704962052,93.2606497020461,95.0245932084508,95.1840579039417,
                         267.025391345844,103.190876314417,83.7450325773098,
                         119.383498271462,38.9962126817554,78.502263085451,
                         257.781351374928,152.138987567276,346.094360763207,
                         6.25871599279344,21.1104894811288,260.104836242273,
                         26.6554267811589,13.0899660103023,2.27121577085927,
                         48.3587435530499,72.6143515692092,5.0223951167427,
                         354.900268542115,14.8733102842234,2.08394991140813,
                         3.44838958978653,6.24167489353567,10.2798880663838,NA,
                         353.38134184014,0.139761414844543,6.34181595779955,
                         4.7543411613442,339.060686764773,1.88942666724324,
                         2.73334667179734,2.5848257667385,5.2891145311296,
                         316.735759525094,3.55257452372462,1.91390282055363,
                         343.923325886019,58.9327583657578,359.243716030382,
                         356.976926999167,263.268143996131,6.55246320785955,
                         79.8888847511262,55.409656863194),
  orientation_degree = c(90,30,90,120,330,90,0,
                         0,90,120,30,30,60,60,30,120,0,NA,0,60,
                         285,90,60,30,270,75,345,15,300,300,0,0,30,15,
                         90,120,30,30,15,30,60,0,60,75,45,0,NA,75,
                         90,270,345,45,270,30,60,270,0,15,30,270,
                         60,15,120,210,270,345,0,0,279,330,0,0,0,330,
                         0,0,60,240,270,315,60,240,60,15,90,0,270,
                         60,0,90,90,90,270,105,90,120,45,75,255,150,
                         345,0,15,255,30,15,0,45,75,0,0,15,0,0,0,
                         11.76470588,NA,0,0,0,0,345,0,0,0,0,315,0,
                         0,345,60,352.5,0,270,0,75,60),
        height_motif = c(1.71,1.46,1.24,1.05,
                         1.43,1.3,1.04,1.55,1.46,1.5,1.87,1.97,2.01,0.91,
                         1.53,0.46,0.6,0.93,0.93,1.36,1.79,1.64,1.92,
                         1.9,1.78,1.79,1.88,1.71,1.76,1.76,1.71,1.66,1.64,
                         1.64,1.73,1.72,1.64,1.69,1.64,1.66,1.48,1.49,
                         1.6,1.47,1.38,1.69,1.06,1.44,1.36,1.52,1.24,
                         1.26,1.16,1.07,1.08,0.85,1.22,1.21,1.15,1.32,
                         1.05,1.05,1.49,1.11,1.26,1.48,1.52,1.56,0.99,
                         0.54,1.08,0.91,0.94,0.71,0.82,1.02,1.43,0.874939,
                         0.756835,0.774067,1.541809,1.497741,1.507385,
                         1.467773,1.484985,1.448933,1.347412,1.668702,1.658203,
                         1.610962,1.609334,1.353169,1.49231,1.363403,
                         1.296956,1.36023,1.365844,1.237427,1.704468,0.552124,
                         0.457844,0.681965,0.846862,1.608765,1.757446,
                         1.973022,2.129658,2.174561,1.716633,1.722432,1.712117,
                         1.703999,0.92334,1.800434,1.343464,1.280598,NA,
                         1.240784,1.330952,1.115987,1.598145,0.380676,0.885132,
                         1.185312,1.153992,1.041819,1.503723,1.492309,
                         1.485962,1.40094,1.358052,1.405171,1.329548,0.882832,
                         0.966858,0.795063,1.15218)
)

code
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggimage)

# It's a random image online
data %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(x = orientation_plot, y = height_motif)
  ) +
  geom_image(
    aes(angle = orientation_degree), size = 0.05, image = 'https://www.pngplay.com/wp-content/uploads/15/Hand-Negative-Down-PNG-HD-Quality.png'
  ) +
  coord_polar() 

session info
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS 15.0.1
ggimage_0.3.3
ggplot2_3.5.1


Update: The things is that when there is some rotation, ggimage adds some blank box around the image

You should split this post, since you can and are even encouraged to answer your own questions.

Thanks @RuiBarradas!!! I knew that option existed and I was totally unable to find it. Thanks :)

I found the problem. The thing is that when adding angle, geom_image seems to be adding some blank square around the image. The solution is to remove the background through the argument image_fun :)
geom_image(
    aes(
      image = image, 
      angle = orientation_degree
      ), 
    image_fun = \(img) {
      img %>%
        magick::image_background('none')
    }
  ) 


